# Toggling bold text on and off with ITextCharacterFormat in Windows Store / Modern UI App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, richtextbox

I'm using the `RichEditBox` to build a simple editor.

I found a piece of code which toggles bold text on a selection within the document window

```
private void RichEditBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var state = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control);
    if ((state & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.B)
        {
            if (Editor.Document.Selection.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                ITextCharacterFormat format = Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat;
                format.Bold = FormatEffect.On;
            }
            else
            {
                // CTRL + B should toggle bold mode on or off here. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I highlight a piece of text, and press `CTRL+B`, it bolds the text. Result. However, anything I type after that point is also in bold.

This is not what I expected. According to the code above, I'm affecting the format of the Selection only.

When I select some text and press `CTRL+B` it should toggle bold formatting **on that selection** and leave the default format as is.

I've tried using FormatEffect.Toggle

```
format.Bold = FormatEffect.Toggle
```

I've tried saving out the Document Character format first, then reapplying

```
ITextCharacterFormat original_format = Editor.Document.GetDefaultCharacterFormat();
ITextCharacterFormat format = Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat;
format.Bold = FormatEffect.On;
Editor.Document.SetDefaultCharacterFormat(original_format);
```

This should reset the default back to what it was after bolding. But it doesn't

I *could* set the selection to nothing, then set `format.Bold = FormatEffect.Off` again, then reselect the text, but that seems like the long way around (and it probably won't work). There must be a simple way to do this?

**NOTE**: I have tagged this with the RichTextBox tag as there is no RichEditBox tag. Can someone with >1500 rep add one?

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behaviour when using `SelectionFont` and setting bold style with richtextbox.

> If the current text selection has more than one font specified, this
>   property is null. If no text is currently selected, the font specified
>   in this property is applied to the current insertion point and to all
>   text that is typed into the control after the insertion point.

It's probably the same issue that you have. 
Wordpad and Word work this way too.

Comment: `If no text is currently selected`

Note my line of logic `if (Editor.Document.Selection.Text.Length > 0)`. This happens when I have made a selection in the document. I *want* it to work the way Wordpad and Word work, but its currently behaving differently. When I **have** made a selection, it bolds both the selection and turns on bold mode.

Comment: In word and wordpad, if you type text just after the text that you have bolded with Ctrl+B, it will be bold. Isn't this what you already have?

Comment: The above quote applies when you type text after the bolded text, after you have pressed ctrl+B. If the `SelectionFont` is in bold style, the text you type will be in bold. The `SelectionFont` property takes the formatting of the text just before the cursor.

Comment: Huh. So it does. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a hack, that works. I'm posting this as an answer for anyone who's stuck, but I'm not accepting the answer, because there must be a better one.

```
private void RichEditBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var state = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control);
    if ((state & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.B)
        {
            if (Editor.Document.Selection.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                // text is selected. make it bold
                ITextCharacterFormat format = 
                     Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat;
                format.Bold = FormatEffect.On;

                var start_pos = Editor.Document.Selection.StartPosition;
                Editor.Document.Selection.StartPosition = 
                     Editor.Document.Selection.EndPosition;
                format.Bold = FormatEffect.Off;

                // Editor.Document.Selection.StartPosition = start_pos;   
                // this is where I was re-selecting the text after switching bold OFF
                // but doing so switches it back on again. which makes no sense                     
            }
            else
            {
                // no text selected. just enable bold mode
                ITextCharacterFormat format = 
                     Editor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat;
                format.Bold = FormatEffect.Toggle;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't perfect, because after you've selected and bolded the text it is automatically de-selected. However in practice I find that this actually works fine for me. Still, it feels like a hack, because it *is* a hack